# SAS Sftp connection issue

Tags: sas, sftp, putty, csc

Currently I'm trying to use sas to connect to sftp server.  I did some researches, it said in order to use sftp method, I need to install openSSH client software and use key authentication for connection.

So I installed puTTY and setup the private/public key. When I test the connection from psftp, I can connect to sftp server without password (use key authentication). As you can see as below, the test file 3.xlsx is on the sftp server.
[image]

But the problem is when I try to get the same file on sas, it has an error "the file does not exist".
[image]

Inside psftp, I could download this test file on my local pc, I have no idea why I cant do the same thing on sas.

Below is my sas sftp connection code:

```
filename output sftp '/3.xlsx'
optionsx='-P 222 -i x:\PuTTY\privatekey.ppk -pw "XXXXX" -V'
host="xxxxxx" user="xxxxxxx" path="x:\PuTTY\psftp.exe" DEBUG;
```

I would be so appreciate if someone can help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Try removing the `/`, and add the `cd='/'` parameter.

Comment: @ChrisJ I tried, it still not working

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd troubleshoot is whether your prompt is an issue.  According to the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=vdmmlcdc&cdcVersion=1.0&docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p0xln1fiwsr340n1xxf4mkmfxp6f.htm&locale=en#p0jdqxuougthe0n1tusa2d36ac69):

> SFTP Access Methods and SFTP Prompts
> The SFTP access method supports only the following prompts. Changing the prompt will disable the SFTP access method.
> For OpenSSH:
>
> > - sftp>
> > - sftp >

You have `psftp>`.  That could be a problem.

The second thing I'd try is, also from the documentation, example 4: Using a Batch File.  Their example:

```
 filename process sftp ' ' host="linuxhost1" user="userid" 
   batchfile="c:/stfpdir/sftpcmds.bat";
data _null_;
   infile process;
run;
```

That would allow you to do more troubleshooting, at minimum (such as a `ls` to see what's available).  There's a lot of potential issues you may be running into, so being able to debug with a commands file would help resolve at least some of them.

You do have the `LS` and `LSA` options, as well, which might help at least debug a bit - maybe easier than the commands file at first.

Comment: Hi Joe, I tried to test simple cmd like 'ls' or 'lsa' first but its not working. According to SAS doc, if I just want to get the file list, I could keep that external file to empty quotation (filename test sftp ''). But if I do this, I will get error like directory or file '' does not exist. That's why I am so confused now.

Comment: Then it sounds like the prompt may indeed be an issue, or else you may have other connectivity issues.